# Safe to blank /etc/securetty?

Tags: linux, tty, aws

Assuming one is operating in AWS and there are no ways to connect via a non-pts terminal, is it safe to blank the /etc/securetty file? Are there any possible unintended consequences? I can't think of any, but I'm just looking for a second opinion.

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer I believe to be acceptable in the RHEL Security Guide:

> To prevent the root user from logging in, remove the contents of /etc/securetty

#### References

- https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Security_Guide/sec-Controlling_Root_Access.html

Comment: **This is not the case on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS**. Be sure to verify (run `su -` on a virtual terminal or `Ctrl+Alt+F2` and log in as root) before assuming that this works.